# Copy text upon clicking on icon in v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to figure out how to allow users to copy their login details when they click the copy icon. How to get the value of the relevant v-text-field?

I thought I should use @click:append and link it to a method. However, I struggle how to get a value.

```
<template>
  <v-card class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 p-6 px-16" elevation="4">
    <div class="title h2 mb-10 text-uppercase text-center">
      Success
      <v-icon color="green" x-large>
        mdi-check-circle
      </v-icon>
    </div>

    <v-text-field
      :value="newAccount.login"
      label="Login"
      outlined
      readonly
      append-icon="mdi-content-copy"
      @click:append="copy('login')"
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-text-field
      :value="newAccount.password"
      label="Password"
      outlined
      readonly
      append-icon="mdi-content-copy"
    ></v-text-field>

  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["newAccount"],
  data() {
    return {
      copied: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    copy(target) {
      if (target === "login") {
        console.log("login is clicked");
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `v-text-field` is available from its `value` property. Apply a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `v-text-field` to get a reference to the component programmatically from [`vm.$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs), then use `.value` off of that:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    ref="login"
    @click:append="copy('login')"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    copy(field) {
      console.log('value', this.$refs[field].value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could access the nested template ref of `v-text-field`'s `<input>`, which has a [`ref` named "input"](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dc19b82/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L401), so `copy()` would access it from `this.$refs[field].$refs.input`. Then, you could [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) the text value, and [execute a `copy` command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#using_execcommand()):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    copy(field) {
      const input = this.$refs[field].$refs.input
      input.select()
      document.execCommand('copy')
      input.setSelectionRange(0,0) // unselect
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zYoyBRN?editors=1010)